# Python PySimpleGUI event does not fire from string list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, pysimplegui

```py
    file_list = []
            for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
                file_list.append(Path(file).stem)        
    
    ...(code making buttons here doesn't effect while statement)
    
    
    while True:
                event, values = button_window.read()
                print(event)
                if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                    break
                elif event == any(file_list[0:len(file_list)]): #(also tried a list comprehension here too)
                    open_file = open(f"{event}.txt","r+")
                    read_text = open_file.read()
                    print(read_text)
                    open_file.close()
                    break
```

If I change the event to the string in the list it does fire. So I believe it is my list comprehension/ any statement here.

Comment: `event == any(file_list[0:len(file_list)])` is same as `event == any(file_list)`. In your case, `any(file_list[0:len(file_list)])` will get `True` if any txt file found, `False` if no txt file found. So your event work only for True case, `event == True` and it looks like not true for most of cases.

Comment: Thanks Jason, realised my mistake by changing it to the 'in' operator it now works as intentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this silly mistake with the 'in' operator which had completely slipped my mind. So the elif statement now reads:

```py
    elif event in file_list:
            open_file = open(f"{event}.txt","r+")
            read_text = open_file.read()
            print(read_text)
            open_file.close()
```